# SQL - Extracting ORDID having Item = "Tent" only

Tags: sql

I am trying to extract records (ORDID) having ITEM = Tent only. for example

```
ID     ORDID     ITEM

1       10       Tent 
2       10       Truck 
3       20       Tent  
4       20       Tent  
5       20       Truck  
6       30       Tent  
7       30       Tent
```

Result:

```
ID     ORDID    ITEM

6       30      Tent  
7       30      Tent
```

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, ORDID, ITEM
FROM YourTable
WHERE ITEM = 'Tent'
  AND ORDID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ORDID 
                    FROM YourTable
                    WHERE ITEM <> 'Tent')
```

Comment: +1, I am impressed that you are able to figure out that this is what he wants.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: seemed like the only logical explanation for the results he seems to want .... :-)